# ListView animation when item is deleted using Dismissible

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using `Dismissible` to dismiss the items, but when an item is dismissed I get default boring animation. Is there a way to change that animation like Gmail does?

Example:

[image]

My own animation (not smooth)

[image]

**So, in my animation, you can see slight pause when the item is deleted and next item coming up on the screen taking up old item position.**

Comment: This animation is written in `_DismissibleState` in `_startResizeAnimation` method. So, customization is only way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rémi Rousselet for his efforts.

Finally I found the reason for that ugly animation. Never use `itemExtent` when you are planning to use `Dismissible`. I was mad, I used it.

Comment: See, it's the default animation :p Your problem is most likely `DecoratedBox` or `Opacity` unless you do some heavy stuff in the gesturedetector

Comment: Thanks to you I will try to post my delete animations screenshot too

Comment: Please see updated question. For simplicity, I removed my Column and put there just a ListTile hoping for some smoothness but still it showed ugly animation (Also read the bold line there)

Comment: You probably should edit your question to include the code. It seems you so something wrong that break the animation

Comment: Ok. I will put the complete code (in around 30 mins) to reproduce this ugly animation. I know you can definitely help me after all you are the person with highest reputation in (Flutter tag)

Comment: The moment I removed `itemExtent` my deep buried widget tree is showing smoother animation. In your answer, you can simply add this property and your nice animation will turn ugly. I just tried it.

Comment: Yeah but it's normal. That property fixes the size, so the resize animation will obviously break

Comment: So, is there any solution to use itemExtent and still have resize animation to work as expected?

Comment: No it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

That's the default animation of `Dismissible`.

```
List<String> content;

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: content.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(content[index]),
      onDismissed: (_) {
        setState(() {
          content = List.from(content)..removeAt(index);
        });
      },
      background: Container(color: Colors.green),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(content[index]),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: What do you mean? It's included directly into Dismissible

Comment: You gave the code, so where can I find the animation which I can change? Does that mean, we can't change the animation? I am looking to implement my own animation when the item is deleted

Comment: The code I gave does exactly the animation you added as gif

Comment: Let me clarify the things, the code that you gave was the similar to the one used by me. When I dismiss an item, I can see the default animation but the gif that I added has got little bit slower/smoother animation. Is there any way to customize that animation (not only the duration but also complete animation)

Comment: Still unclear. What do you mean by _complete animation_ ? What do you want _exactly_ ?

Comment: I am adding the screenshot of my delete (which is default animation) in the question in a moment to make it more clear.